# How to deploy web api webhook sender in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

Hello to all I would like to ask how to deploy a web API webhook sender in your local IIS?
What are the configurations needed in IIS?

Scenario:
The weird thing is when I'm debugging my web API (webhook sender) solution in IIS express together with the win form app (webhook receiver) it works properly. But when I tried to deploy the webhook sender in my local IIS and try to run the webhook receiver it works as it is upon registering the WebHookUri, Description, Secret, etc. but when the NotifyAsync is executed it doesn't notify the receiver.

In short in IIS express it works properly and in local IIS it's not.

Please let me know what am I missing?

Kind regards.

Comment: May I know if there is any error message when you execute notifyAsync ? Could you please provide more details ?

Comment: Can could you please use another client(such as postman) to test if can request the receiver when you deploy it to local IIS ?

Comment: Hello Hury, thank you for responding to my question.
No, I don't get any errors when I execute the notifyAsync.

I did it this way to be exact.
When I do the debug mode for the webhook sender in IIS express the URL is http:://localhost:64654 then on the webhook receiver which is winform I use http://192.168.9.55 it registered successfully and when the notifyAsync executed the winform received the webhook data.

But when I tried the same thing the difference is I deploy the webhook sender in my local IIS with the following URL http://localhost/mywebhook then the issue occurred.

Comment: What am I missing? is that the receiver URL? in addition I use windows authentication as I try it with anonymous authentication the receiver cannot register to the sender.

Would you mind telling me what is the correct URL to use on the receiver side? I'm just trying to refer to the sample webhook solution that I've found: https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks

Comment: The IP address that I'm using in the receiver is the machine's IP address. Is this a possible issue?

Comment: May I know if you request the sender with `localhost/mywebhook` ? or `localhost:portnum/mywebhook` ?

Comment: From my local IIS, I did the request without a port number localhost/mywebhook.

Comment: Could you please have a try with add the port number ?

Comment: So you mean in my local IIS from the Default Web Site under bindings should I need to change the port 80 or add a new one?

Comment: No, you do not need to change the port from 80 to another number.

Comment: I tried to change port 80 to 6789 still not working. how about on the receiver side does the URL seems wrong? "No, you do not need to change the port from 80 to another number." Sorry, my bad. 

What I did earlier is to add a new port from bindings then I tried still not working then I do the above one.

Do you mean I put port 80 on the URL? So sorry.

Comment: Could you please have a try to request the receiver in postman ?

Comment: What do you mean? what should I put on the postman? Do you mean to do the receiver registration in postman?

Comment: What should I do to make a request in postman where the sender application in my local IIS is windows authenticate enabled? I've got Unauthorized in postman.

Comment: You can disable windows authentication temporarily.

Comment: I disable the windows authentication temporarily and enable the anonymous authentication then I've got "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Comment: Here is the info URL from postman http://localhost/MyWebhook/api/webhooks/registrations?Registration={WebHookUri: "http://192.168.9.55//api/webhook",  Description: "event is posted.",  Secret: "w65XKNlBVc6YhhMOTNaZ+YUiMJ0830Lw",  Filters: { "Event1" }, Properties: {"prop1" : null}  }

Comment: I think you can use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to check the notify receiver.

Comment: I will try your suggestion thank you. by the way isn't maybe the issue is coming from the receiver URL? because I deploy the sender in my local IIS and I run the receiver on the same machine using the machine's IP address.

Comment: I think you can also check if there is any cors limit on the receiver side. You can modify the web.config file of receiver side to allow all by referring to this [link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) and check if the receiver can be called. If it can be called, it implies the problem may be caused by cors.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to check my local IIS config vs IIS express config and tried to make it the same but still it is not working. I tried also to compare the trace logs of my local IIS and IIS express the two are the same however it still not working so I tried to add the cors settings into my receiver app (windows form app) config still not working. I think there must be a certain setting in IIS express that does enable in my local IIS.

Comment: Is there a way to get the list of the registered subscribers in the sender's post method?
Could you please tell me what exact URL does the receiver has?
I'm very confused. for example, my sender web API deployed in http://cvb/webhook/. then on each client what URL should they use in this line using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(webhookReceiverBaseAddress))?

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp.net code, I just analyze your issue. Since the code can run success when you start it in IIS express, so I don't think the problem was caused by code. So I suggest you to check the request failed tracing and cors. It's strange for your problem, I think you can type some logs in your code and you may find the logs in the path `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.